# How to give class parameter name to function to change this parameter

Tags: python

I have a function to remove nan-values from numpy arrays:

```
    def _remove_nans(self):
        def get_without_nans(array):
            mask = np.invert(np.isnan(array))
            return array[mask]

        self.average_dynamic_depth = get_without_nans(self.average_dynamic_depth)
        # ... many more similar lines to clear more arrays
```

This works, but is hard to read and more importantly its easy to make copy&paste errors like:

```
self.a = get_without_nans(self.b)  # <= b instead of a!
```

Is it possible to give the parameter name as a parameter to the function get_without_nans() insteads of an array? So that I could somehow call it like:

```
get_without_nans("self.average_dynamic_depth")
# or
get_without_nans("average_dynamic_depth")
```

?

Comment: Instead of doing this, are you sure you couldn't write `get_without_nans` in a way that it modifies its input rather than returning a new object? (I don't know numpy, so I don't know if it doesn't do that already.)

Comment: @Dainel Roseman Not sure (I'm also new to numpy). I thought the arrays are immutable (but that might not be true) or if they are mutable, its not recommended to pass a mutable to a function, is it? BUt I will look into this suggestion. A String-representation (or something similar) would help me to make other things easy, e.g. by creating a list with all the names at one place, and then passing this list in one line to functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr). The code would look like:

```
def _remove_nans(self):
    def get_without_nans(self, attrname):
        array = getattr(self, attrname, None)
        if array is not None:
            mask = np.invert(np.isnan(array))
            setattr(self, attrname, array[mask])
        else:
            raise AttributeError("some error message")

    get_without_nans(self, "average_dynamic_depth")
    # ... many more similar lines to clear more arrays
```